# Widget state updated by scaffold floatingActionButton

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a scaffold which includes a `floatingActionButton` as demonstrated below:

```
return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
            title : new Text('Test Flutter'),
        ),
        body: new Center(
            child: new ListSection(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
            child: new Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: null
        ),
    );
```

List section:

```
class ListSection extends StatelessWidget
{
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Container(
            child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                    new WeekSection(),
//                  new MonthSection(),
//                  new YearSection()
                ]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Lastly WeekSection is defined as follow:

```
class WeekSection extends StatefulWidget
{
    @override
    _WeekSectionState createState() => new _WeekSectionState();
}
```

How would I go about using the `floatingActionButton.onPressed` to updated the sate in `_WeekSectionState`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic way would be to have a private var in your `MyApp` where scaffold, and to pass the reference to that field all the way down to the `WeekSection`,

So you pass this variable trough constructor to the `ListSection` and pass it down again trough constructor to `WeekSection`.

inside `WeekSectionState` you can access it as `widget.someField` from `WeekSection`;

Later, when you call `setState` inside `MyApp` directly in the listener of the FloatingActionButton it will rebuild `WeekSection` because the Widget that holds information for the state has changed. The flutter checks all the children that need rebuilding.